# bootstrap responsive confirmation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image]

html

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="confirmation-popout" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" title="">Confirmation on bottom</a>`

script

`$('#example').confirmation()
```

Its not being responsive as you see in the image. I want that to be responsive along with the confirmation button

The issue is when i click on the confirmation on bottom button. there is confirmation pop up. so when i resize my window the confirmation box is fixed not being responsive.

Please check the link provided for testing the responsiveness.

can you help me in fixing this [Link](http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Now where is your respective codes ? you just provided one liner codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to refresh the confirmation('show') on window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('a + .popover').prev().confirmation('show');
});
```

Here is the working code sample. Run the code snippet in full screen and resize the window.

```js
$(function() {

  $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation();
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('a + .popover').prev().confirmation('show');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/assets/css/docs.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>

<script src="http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="bs-docs-example tooltip-demo">
    <ul class="bs-docs-tooltip-examples">
      <li><a class="btn" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="left" data-original-title="" title="">Confirmation on left</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="top" data-original-title="" title="">Confirmation on top</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" title="">Confirmation on bottom</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="btn" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="right" data-original-title="" title="">Confirmation on right</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```